# Element is already the child of another element when adding different images in a UI Element

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

I am trying to add different page contents in order to pass it to the Print Manager interface. However, when trying to add multiple BitmapImages, it's returning a "Element is already the child of another element." error.

Here's what my current code looks like:

```
Canvas page = new Canvas
        {
            Width = pageDescription.PageSize.Width,
            Height = pageDescription.PageSize.Height
        };

        Canvas viewablePage = new Canvas()
        {
            Width = pageDescription.ViewablePageSize.Width,
            Height = pageDescription.ViewablePageSize.Height
        };

        viewablePage.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, pageDescription.Margin.Width);
        viewablePage.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, pageDescription.Margin.Height);

        // The image "frame" which also acts as a viewport
        Grid photoView = new Grid
        {
            Width = pageDescription.PictureViewSize.Width,
            Height = pageDescription.PictureViewSize.Height
        };
```

The foreach loop wherein a different image is added to the a different page

```
foreach(var btm in bitmapImages)
            {
                Image image = new Image
                {
                    Source = btm,
                    HorizontalAlignment = Windows.UI.Xaml.HorizontalAlignment.Center,
                    VerticalAlignment = Windows.UI.Xaml.VerticalAlignment.Center
                };

                // Use the real image size when croping or if the image is smaller then the target area (prevent a scale-up).
                if ((btm.PixelWidth <= pageDescription.PictureViewSize.Width &&
                    btm.PixelHeight <= pageDescription.PictureViewSize.Height))
                {
                    image.Stretch = Stretch.None;
                    image.Width = bitmap.PixelWidth;
                    image.Height = bitmap.PixelHeight;
                }
                photoView.Children.Add(image);
                viewablePage.Children.Add(photoView);
                page.Children.Add(viewablePage);
                pages.Add(page);
            }
```

bitmapImages is a list of bitmaps. It works if there's only one image to be added but when adding < 1 image to a page, it returns the error. Do you have any suggestions on how should I implement this?

Thanks alot.

Comment: `pages.Add(page);` Could you explain what `pages` is?

Comment: Hi @JunjieZhu-MSFT, it's a list of pages to be added later on at printdocs.addpages method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each UI element in UWP can only be used in the UI in one place at one time.
You need to define the UI element every loop.

```
foreach(var btm in bitmapImages)
{
    Canvas page = new Canvas
    {
        Width = pageDescription.PageSize.Width,
        Height = pageDescription.PageSize.Height
    };

    Canvas viewablePage = new Canvas()
    {
        Width = pageDescription.ViewablePageSize.Width,
        Height = pageDescription.ViewablePageSize.Height
    };

    viewablePage.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, pageDescription.Margin.Width);
    viewablePage.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, pageDescription.Margin.Height);

    // The image "frame" which also acts as a viewport
    Grid photoView = new Grid
    {
        Width = pageDescription.PictureViewSize.Width,
        Height = pageDescription.PictureViewSize.Height
    };
    Image image = new Image
    {
        Source = btm,
        HorizontalAlignment = Windows.UI.Xaml.HorizontalAlignment.Center,
        VerticalAlignment = Windows.UI.Xaml.VerticalAlignment.Center
    };

    // Use the real image size when croping or if the image is smaller then the target area (prevent a scale-up).
    if ((btm.PixelWidth <= pageDescription.PictureViewSize.Width &&
        btm.PixelHeight <= pageDescription.PictureViewSize.Height))
    {
        image.Stretch = Stretch.None;
        image.Width = bitmap.PixelWidth;
        image.Height = bitmap.PixelHeight;
    }
    photoView.Children.Add(image);
    viewablePage.Children.Add(photoView);
    page.Children.Add(viewablePage);
    pages.Add(page);
}
```

Comment: It returns the same error I'm afraid :( Maybe I should separate the adding of UI elements? :O

Comment: My test is fine, define the UI element in loop. Maybe you need to provide more information about your code.

Comment: Hi Junjie, basically this line of code generates pages to be printed and added to the Print Manager. The foreach loop traverses to all PDF pages that were converted to Bitmaps in order to be added as a UI Element. Am I doing this right or is my approach incorrect?

Comment: @MartinKing The error means you are adding a same `child` element to different parent controls. This is not allowed. Using foreach loop is ok, but you need to make sure all the parameter objects is created inside the loop to avoid reusing. Without knowing your detailed code, we don't know what exactly causes the issue. Please double check in which line of code it throws the same error when using JunJie's solution. The parameter in that line is the object that being reused. Then what you need to do is to make sure that object will be created inside the loop not outside the loop.

Comment: Hi Roy and Junjie, actually, I managed to make it work. Thanks alot! :)